# Was Stack Exchange named after Experts Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, experts-exchange, trademark

Was Stack Exchange named after Experts Exchange, or is the former using the word "Exchange" a coincidence?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I remember I first heard this name from the Stack Overflow podcast.  They were talking about "knowledge exchange" and they added stack to the mix and it turns out the actual product was named after that.

Since one of the unofficial goals of Stack Overflow has been "expertsexchange.com without the evil," I wouldn't be surprised that it has indirectly influenced the naming, but I can't imagine they've named the product after the hyphen site intentionally.

Comment: It's [Podcast 58](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/podcast-58/); the discussion starts around 4:50. Quoting Joel: *Jason told us it was a knowledge exchange [...] Nobody uses that word, but what the hell, I like it. And, uhm, so the product is a knowledge exchange server I guess. And we want to have, uh, we want to allude at least to the original Stack Overflow. So the long version of the name might be something like "The Stack Overflow Knowledge Exchange Server Hosted Edition".*

Comment: @balpha: Wow. I did remember it correctly! I miss the podcast. Jeff, Joel, I WANT THE PODCAST BACK! :(

Comment: @balpha TSOKESHE has a kinda neat ring to it...

Comment: TSOKESHE "so catchy"

Comment: @Grace I'm imagining that in some outdated language it means, "inedible fibrous root".

Comment: @AdamDavis Funny... I thought katana-esque weapon.

Comment: Every time I see "expertsexchange.com" without the hyphens, I read "Expert Sex Change". Geez, talk about Freudian...

Comment: @Yawus: Good that something like that can't happen with the "S. Exchange" we use here...

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange, Inc is located in One Exchange Plaza, 26th Floor, NY NY 10006. Coincidence? I don't know.

Comment: Exchange Plaza may be named after the New York Stock Exchange, at least [according to one MSO commenter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124001/update-stack-exchanges-address#comment331200_124001).

Comment: @PopularDemand that's a reasonable assumption but its name is actually derived from the Merchant's Exchange Building which [burned in 1835](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Fire_of_New_York), which then moved north one block to wall street. Incidentally the name "Exchange Plaza" doesn't appear on the property description of [the deed](http://a836-acris.nyc.gov/Scripts/DocSearch.dll/ViewImage?Doc_ID=2006070300408001) or any of the New York city tax maps but rather "Exchange Alley" so I suspect some real estate maneuvering here even though the Street Signs do read "Exchange Plaza".