# What does “Stack” mean here?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, trademark

Inspired by a [question on English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14010/what-does-stack-mean-here?rq=1):

> “You know what I like about people?” he asks, staring into the camera. “They **stack** so well.” He’s been reading newspaper coverage of the carnage he’s created.
>
> -- *www.hollywoodreporter.com*

The question on ELL was about what "stack" meant in that context, and the result related to the insanity implied by a murderer's association of people with corpses neatly stacked in a mass grave.

Now I want to know about another use of "stack". Stack Overflow was one of the original three SE Q&A sites, named after the stack data structure used to store a computer program's continuation. (A "stack overflow" happens when functions call other functions so deeply that return addresses and automatic variables exceed the amount of memory reserved for them.) The **Exchange** part [comes from "knowledge exchange"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71757/was-stack-exchange-named-after-experts-exchange) but suggests a connection to ExpertS-exChange, a competing "knowledge exchange" site notorious for its paywall and other [dark patterns](http://darkpatterns.org/experts-exchange-com-october-2010/) in how it complies with [Google's first click free policy](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/40543?hl=en).

But why was Stack Overflow, and not Super User or Server Fault, chosen to contribute the other half of the name of **Stack** Exchange? The [trademark use guidelines](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) cited in the [other branding post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9024/how-are-stack-exchange-sites-officially-branded) didn't answer my question.

Comment: ["Think about a Pez dispenser. That's your mental model for a stack..."](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/148524/31260)

Comment: I'd rather say the "exchange" comes more from the direct connection to "stock exchange", given the existing prevalence of "stack" (as explained in *Oded*'s answer).

Comment: @ChristianRau - the exchange bit came from the concept of "Knowledge Exchange". As mentioned in [this podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/podcast-56/).

Comment: @cVplZ That question is about where SO's name comes from and mine is about why SO was chosen for SE's name.

Comment: SuperExchange would sound pretentious and ServerExchange would have implied used hardware for sale.

Comment: @Won't Fault Exchange likewise has problems. That leaves User Exchange. Or was it taken at the time?

Comment: Same issue with ServerExchange.  Would imply slave trade.

Answer (score 13):

It starts with the technical programming term for a stack - this is the name of a data structure (a stack), where one conceptually stacks up items.

This term was used in the name of the first site - Stack Overflow, which references [one type of error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) that can occur in the usage of stacks - adding more items than either the data structure or the computer can hold (this is a slightly simplified explanation, but is enough for the purpose of explaining the name).

With Stack Overflow becoming a hugely popular site, when the concept of creating many many other sites using the same software engine came up and a name was sought, keeping the word stack both for being recognizable by Stack Overflow users and in that it has the other meaning (one could think of it as a stacking of sites in different topic - the logo alludes to that usage). Stack Overflow was (and still is) the largest site in the network, by a long margin.

Though, a third usage of the term stack comes to mind in computer/IT - a technical stack (meaning the choice of technologies used for a system), but I doubt that one contributed to the name.

Comment: Any idea who came up with the name? My guess is Joel, maybe ping him to come over and give some details, if he would like to? :)

Comment: I'm not sure who first suggested the name, but it was the highest voted suggestion on Jeff Atwood's blog. http://blog.codinghorror.com/help-name-our-website/

Comment: @ShadowWizard - which name Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange?

Comment: Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Sha - Stack from "Stack Overflow", Exchange from "Knowledge Exchange". No idea who came up with the portmanteau. (the comment/link from connor confused me)