# Why are some sites "overflow" and some sites "exchange"?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-name

There's mathoverflow.stackexchange and math.stackexchange.  There seem to be a number of sites that are have both an "overflow" site and a "exchange" name as well.  Eh?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do the names of the Stack Overflow trilogy sites come from?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61541/where-do-the-names-of-the-stack-overflow-trilogy-sites-come-from)

Comment: @JAL Doesn't seem to explain anything about mathoverflow and math.stackexchange, which are not from the original trilogy.

Comment: @zaq hmm, can't find one related specifically to the math sites, maybe this can provide more info? [Where did the name “Stack Exchange” come from?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247850/242209)

Comment: Outside of MO and Math SE, what other overflow-exchange combinations are you thinking of?

Comment: I'm trying to remember where else I saw this.  I think I might be just getting confused at using the name "stackoverflow.com" instead of something like programming.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Actually [so] and [programmers.se] are two completely different sites.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two Stack Exchange sites with the suffix "Overflow": [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) (as well as Stack Overflow sites in other languages).

The name "Stack Overflow" was [chosen by community voting in 2008](https://blog.codinghorror.com/help-name-our-website/), beating out suggestions like privatevoid.com and algorithmical.com (full poll results [here](http://www.addpoll.com/results?14407)). I couldn't tell you why those 1,721 people voted for it, but the name stuck, and over eight years later, it's still around.

MathOverflow has [a different history](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/753/74879). It was originally an independent site, launched in late 2009 but [inspired by Stack Overflow](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/186/whats-the-story-behind-mathoverflow-/) (hence the name "Math*Overflow*"). It then joined Stack Exchange in 2013.

The names for the rest of the Stack Exchange network - and the name "Stack Exchange" - have been covered in [Where do the names of the Stack Overflow trilogy sites come from?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61541/274942) (for the Trilogy) and [Where did the name "Stack Exchange" come from?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247850/274942). "Stack Exchange" was [short for](https://web.archive.org/web/20091027022628/https://stackexchange.com/?) "The Stack Overflow Knowledge Exchange" ([no "Platform"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247850/where-did-the-name-stack-exchange-come-from#comment812168_247855)), in the beginning. That's quite the mouthful.

There are other non-Trilogy sites without names of the form "[X] Stack Exchange". Many of them are discussed in [Why do some Stack Exchange sites have their own domain names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248453/274942). Quite a few came from Stack Exchange 1.0 sites and outside sites - which have their own long, complicated histories.