# What does 'StackExchange' mean?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stack-exchange-history

As the question implies, I am talking about the name of this website. It has evidently been formed from 'Stack' & 'Exchange'. But what does it mean and why was this name chosen  ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Where did the name "Stack Exchange" come from?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247850/where-did-the-name-stack-exchange-come-from).

Comment: @user289905 I am not sure whether it answers my question or not .Does it  ?  zd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stack Exchange is the short form of "Stack Overflow Knowledge Exchange Platform", which was the original name of the platform.

This is officially confirmed by Joel Spolsky in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247850/where-did-the-name-stack-exchange-come-from#comment812168_247855):

> that was a typo on the Fog Creek site; It was actually [Stack Overflow Knowledge Exchange](https://web.archive.org/web/20091027022628/https://stackexchange.com/?) shortened to "StackExchange"