# Stack Exchange name pun?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange

Is 'Stack Exchange' a pun on 'Stock Exchange'?

Or does it refer to programming 'stacks', and so not related at all?

A similar question is  [[here]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247850/where-did-the-name-stack-exchange-come-from).

However I am thinking 'Stack' to 'Stock' is a deliberate ploy.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. According to [this comment from balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71757/was-stack-exchange-named-after-experts-exchange#comment173010_71758) a long time ago:

> It's [Podcast 58](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/podcast-58/); the discussion starts around 4:50. Quoting Joel: Jason told us it was a knowledge exchange [...] Nobody uses that word, but what the hell, I like it. And, uhm, so the product is a knowledge exchange server I guess. And we want to have, uh, we want to allude at least to the original Stack Overflow. So the long version of the name might be something like "The Stack Overflow Knowledge Exchange Server Hosted Edition".

So no, it is more related to *knowledge exchange* than *stock exchange*.

Comment: The ***real*** pun is more likely on [the hyphen site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange).